# Deformation of (locally) ringed spaces and of their abelian categories of modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, deformation-theory, abelian-categories

I am interested in the general theory of deformations locally ringed spaces in the same language of the deformation theory of schemes/varieties that is already widely available. I am aware for example of what is written down in the stacks project (for example [Tag 08UX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08UX)) but I'm failing to find a more through treatment specially one that would put in contrast the differences with the special case of schemes/varieties. In my literature review, however, I stumbled into the following quote in

*Lowen, Wendy; van den Bergh, Michel*, [**Deformation theory of abelian categories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-06-03871-2), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 358, No. 12, 5441-5483 (2006). [ZBL1113.13009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1113.13009).

> These results confirm the fundamental insight of Gerstenhaber and Schack [6,
> 8] that one should define the deformations of a ringed space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ not as the deformations of $\mathcal{O}_X$ as a sheaf of k-algebras, but rather as the deformations of the k-linear category $\mathfrak{u}$ (or of the “diagram” $(\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{B}})$ in case $X\in \mathcal{B}$). These “virtual” deformations are nothing but the deformations of the abelian category $Mod(\mathcal{O}_{X})$.

The cited category $\mathfrak{u}$ is an appropriately defined category which is used to show that the deformations of the category of presheaves of modules over an appropriate basis $\mathcal{B}$ are equivalent to deformations of sheaves of modules over $\mathcal{O}_{X}$

I have skimmed through the literature including the cited papers and while I have found some indication of the exact meaning of this claim I am still confused. My interpretation is that the claim is either strictly noncommutative in nature ( so passing through a reconstruction theorem ), or deformations of this abelian category directly give the 'correct' deformation theory of the space in some sense ( for example the relationship with Hochschild cohomology in *Lowen, Wendy; van den Bergh, Michel*, [**Hochschild cohomology of Abelian categories and ringed spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2004.11.010), Adv. Math. 198, No. 1, 172-221 (2005). [ZBL1095.13013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1095.13013).)

My first question would then be, could somebody clarify what exactly is the quote saying?

My second question is then, if the space is a (sufficiently nice) scheme then am I to understand that the deformation theory of the  category of quasi-coherent sheaves controls the deformations of the scheme as I would find it written in classical texts?

Thanks in advance

The cited papers on the quote are, respectively:

*Gerstenhaber, M.; Schack, S. D.*, [**On the deformation of algebra morphisms and diagrams**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1999369), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 279, 1-50 (1983). [ZBL0544.18005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0544.18005).
and,

*Gerstenhaber, Murray; Schack, Samuel D.*, [**The cohomology of presheaves of algebras. I: Presheaves over a partially ordered set**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2001114), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 310, No. 1, 135-165 (1988). [ZBL0706.16021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0706.16021).

Comment: The quotation is non-commutative in nature, ensuring the (unmodified) Hochschild complex governs deformations. For commutative deformations, the relevant cohomology theory is Andre-Quillen and no similar issue arises; the commutative and non-commutative deformations only agree in special cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon Pridham notes in the comments, the quote should be understood noncommutatively. In fact, in the introduction Lowen and Van den Bergh write

> Deformation theory of abelian categories is important for non-commutative algebraic geometry. One of the possible goals of non-commutative algebraic geometry is to understand the abelian (or triangulated) categories which have properties close to those of the (derived) category of (quasi-)coherent sheaves on a scheme.

As you observe, this is a natural point of view when identifying a ringed space $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ with its category of quasi-coherent sheaves by considering spectra of Abelian categories as in the [Gabriel–Rosenberg reconstruction theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gabriel-Rosenberg+theorem).

To answer your second question, the deformations of the Abelian category $\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)$ of quasi-coherent sheaves contain classical deformations of $X$ as a special case, but in general admit *more* deformations than $X$.

The difference becomes quite clear when looking at the space of first-order deformations up to equivalence (i.e. the tangent space of the deformation functor).

For example, for **smooth** $X$ one gets

- $\mathrm H^1 (\mathcal T_X)$ for deformations of $X$
- $\mathrm H_{\mathrm{Ab}}^2 (\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)) \simeq \mathrm{HH}^2 (X) 
   \simeq \mathrm H^0 (\Lambda^2 \mathcal T_X) \oplus \mathrm H^1 (\mathcal T_X) \oplus \mathrm H^2 (\mathcal O_X)$ for deformations of $\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)$, i.e. you get two new types of deformations: the direct summand $\mathrm H^0 (\Lambda^2 \mathcal T_X)$ corresponds to quantizations of algebraic Poisson structures and $\mathrm H^2 (\mathcal O_X)$ to twists of the structure sheaf.

For **affine** $X = \mathrm{Spec} (A)$ with $A$ commutative one gets

- $\mathrm{Har}^2 (A, A)$ for deformations of $X$ (Harrison / André–Quillen cohomology which controls *commutative* deformations of $A$ which are trivial if $A$ is smooth)
- $\mathrm{HH}^2 (A, A)$ for deformations of $\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)$ (Hochschild cohomology which controls *associative* deformations of $A$).

If you want to compare deformations of $\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)$ and $X$ on equal footing, you can look at deformations of $\mathcal O_X \vert_{\mathfrak U}$ for some affine open cover $\mathfrak U$ closed under $\cap$ either

- as a twisted presheaf of associative algebras — this is equivalent to deformations of $\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)$ as Abelian category by the results of Lowen and Van den Bergh
- as a presheaf of commutative algebras — this is equivalent to classical deformations of $X$ (see for example [1]).

The "insight" by Gerstenhaber and Schack was that the former type of deformations of the diagram $\mathcal O_X \vert_{\mathfrak U}$ give a useful generalization of "deformation" of a ringed space, and Lowen and Van den Bergh show that this corresponds to the deformation theory of $\mathrm{Qcoh} (X)$ as Abelian category.

[1] *Lepri, Emma; Manetti, Marco*, [**On deformations of diagrams of commutative algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-37114-2_6), Colombo, Elisabetta (ed.) et al., Birational geometry and moduli spaces. Collected papers presented at the INdAM workshop, Rome, Italy, June 11–15, 2018. Cham: Springer. Springer INdAM Ser. 39, 77-107 (2020). [ZBL1440.13066](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1440.13066).

Comment: Ah, that is very clear now, thank you lots. I think my confusion was in not knowing if schemes deform as ringed spaces in the same way they do as schemes so I didn't know how to compare with the categorical theory.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your second question is "no", I think.

Let's assume that sufficiently nice means that it is a smooth algebraic variety over a field of characteristic $0$. Then, as written in Severin Barmeier's answer, first order deformations of the abelian category of modules are given by $HH^2(X)\simeq H^0(X,\wedge^2 T_X)\oplus H^1(X,T_X)\oplus H^2(X,\mathcal O_X)$ [note that this isomorphism is a consequence of the Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg iso]. Now, only $H^1(X,T_X)$ amounts for classical first order deformations of $X$ as a scheme. $H^0(X,\wedge^2 T_X)$ provides first order (possibly noncommutative) deformations of the product of $\mathcal O_X$, while $H^2(X,\mathcal O_X)$ provides first order deformations of the glueing data of $\mathcal O_X$ (these are gerby/stacky deformations of $\mathcal O_X$).

All together, these three parts provide first order deformations of $\mathcal O_X$ as an algebroid stack, in the sense of Kontsevich (see Appendix A of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106006), as well as papers by Yekutieli or Kashiwara-Schapira).

As for your first question, the claims says that deforming the structure sheaf $\mathcal O_X$ as a sheaf of (possibly noncommutative) algebras is not enough to get all deformations of $Mod(\mathcal O_X)$. Indeed, for first order deformation this would only give $H^0(X,\wedge^2 T_X)\oplus H^1(X,T_X)$, and one would miss the part $H^2(X,\mathcal O_X)$. To get all deformations of $Mod(\mathcal O_X)$, the claim says that one shall deform the $k$-linear category $\mathfrak{u}$ (which is essentially the same as deformating $\mathcal O_X$ as an algebroid stack in the sense of Kontsevich- under the assumption that $X$ has a basis $\mathcal B$ so that for every $U\in\mathcal B$, $H^1(U,\mathcal O_U)=H^2(U,\mathcal O_U)=0$).

Comment: Thank you lots! The algebroid stack point of view I find particularly useful for my purposes.

Comment: @AT0 In that case, you might also be interested in the paper [Algebroid prestacks and ringed spaces](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2008-360-03/S0002-9947-07-04354-1/) by Lowen (in addition to the papers by Yekutieli and the book by Kashiwara and Schapira).